# Converting a Webpage to a Google chrome extension

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, backend

I have made a Webpage which:

1. The Users can log into (using Google login), and save their notes or bookmarks there.
2. This webpage also have backend service to store all the notes/bookmarks that is related to that  user.
3. The webpage is connected to this backend directly, no APIs.

So I want to convert this webpage into a Google Chrome extension , and publish it in the chrome web store.

Is that something that is doable ? or it's something that will take a serious redesign of my current webpage's code ?

Comment: Please read ([Developer Program Policies](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/program_policies/#spam) and [quality guidelines FAQ](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/single_purpose/)) before attempting to do this, specifically:

> **Functionality**: Do not post an extension with a single purpose of installing or launching another app, theme, webpage, or extension.

i.e. would need to rewrite; doable and easy are relative.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Neea fixed the text.
about the Google Policy - i admit i don't understand the concept.
I mean: assuming someone has made an extension that can also function as a webpage, does that mean it's not applicable for the webstore ?

Comment: You should think of what functionality extension adds to your existing app, that the website alone currently does not/cannot deliver, then make that extension. Just wrapping a website into an extension can result in flag and takedown.

Comment: @Neea , So basically I need to convert the website into extension, and than add 1+ extra feature to this converted website, Which only Google chrome extension API can provide, got it.